# Data binding in angularJS after selecting an option from dropdown list

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am a newbie in angularJS. please anyone can tell me how to achieve this task to complete,
When I select something from dropdown list the related information will be shown in readonly fields. The following attachment is shown below

[image: imgur-image]

Comment: Show us what you have so far, best: provide a minimal example in [Stackoverflow Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) that can run angularjs code

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this, I would create an array of objects with those three values, iterate over that array and display the package name in the dropdown. Then once selected set a scope variable to be the selected object and then bind the price and validity of that scope variable object to each of those readonly fields.

Angular [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) will help you display only the part of the object that you want in the dropdown.

**EDIT: Here is my solution**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="package_name" id="pack" ng-required="true">
            <option value="">--Select Package Name--</option>
            <option ng-repeat="for item in items" ng-click={change(item)}>{item.item}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-offset-1">Validity</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="validity" id="valid" ng-bind="{{selecteditem.validity}}" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-offset-1">Price</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" ng-bind="{{selecteditem.price}}" readonly="readonly">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

    app.controller('myController',function($scope){
        $scope.selecteditem = {};
        $scope.items = [{ "item": "item1", "validity": "1 month", "price": "0 rupees" }, {  "item": "item2", "validity": "1 year", "price": " 1000 rupees" }];

        $scope.change = function(item) {
            $scope.selecteditem = item;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern

Comment: This is my select statement in html

Comment: <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="package_name" ng-model="package_name" id="pack" ng-required="true">
         <option value="">--Select Package Name--</option>
                <option value="1">Free</option>
                <option value="2">Bronze</option>
               </select>
       </div>

Comment: And below is the code for two readonly fileds in which i have to display json data

Comment: <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-offset-1">Validity</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="validity" id="valid" ng-model="validity" ng-bind="{{details.validity}}" readonly="readonly">
       </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-offset-1">Price</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price"  id="price" ng-model="price" ng-bind="{{details.validity}}" readonly="readonly">
       </div>

Comment: Please send me any other similar kind of link which is related to my task so that I can refer it.....Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to iterate over your array for your select options.

Comment: Also read about [scoping](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). It sounds like the whole [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) might help.

Comment: Dear Sir Here I am only showing json file data in readonly fields This is json file...

Comment: [
    {
 "validity": "1 month",
 "price": "0 rupees"
}, {
 "validity": "1 year",
 "price": " 1000 rupees"
}
]

Comment: I updated my answer with my solution. Also you only need to be using one of ng-model and ng-bind.

Comment: Sir Can you please send me the JSON file also so that I will get some idea about this from that file because in my json file showing some errors.. for your previous solution code "EDIT: Here is my solution".....

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ng-chnage' here, like;

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="mymodel" ng-change="changed(mymodel)">
        <option ng-repeat='b in books'>{{b.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" value={{mymodel}} readonly>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="secondOne" readonly>
</div>

<script>


    var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);

    app.controller('myController',function($scope){

    $scope.books=[{'name':'book1','price':'200' },{'name':'book2','price':'400'}]

    $scope.changed=function(value)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.books.length;i++)
          if($scope.books[i].name==value)
            $("#secondOne").val($scope.books[i].price);
    }
 })
</script>
```

Used jQuery just to select an element.
I didn't make it complex, it's simple easy to understand.

Comment: It's my pleasure if I could help you.

Comment: The value passed to changed() will be the complete object and not the name property of the object.